# ¿Cómo hacer que un metodo encuentre un procedimiento almacenado (sql server)?

Tags: c#, stored-procedure

Cree un procedimiento almacenado para el metodo eliminar, sin embargo cuando ejecuto el programa me sale error y me dice que no pudo encontrar el stored procedure ¿como resuelvo eso?

//Procedimiento almacenado sql server

```
CREATE proc EliminarProductos
@idpro int
as
delete from Productos where @idpro=id
go
```

//Código C#

```
public void Eliminar(int id)
        {
            comando.Connection = conexion.AbrirConexion();
            comando.CommandText = " EliminarProductos ";
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idpro", id);
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            comando.Parameters.Clear();

        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. Verifica que las credenciales del usuario con que realizas las operaciones tengan por default (o que especifiques) la BD/esquema respectivo; así mismo, prueba quitando los espacios a los extremos que sea `comando.CommandText = "EliminarProductos";`.

Comment: Tambien es una buena practica escribir el codigo del procedimiento almacenado con el esquema (por ejemplo dbo.EliminarProductos)